# Exception when execute Keras methods from a Python2.7 Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, keras

I got an exception when I am trying to execute Keras methods like `model.predict(X)` from a python2.7 Thread.

Running the code without threads will work just fine, the issue is that I will have multiple clients accessing the model and using it to predict.

Here is the exception I get [image: screenshot]
Are there any know issues for Python 2.7 in dealing with Thread or this is a bug in Keras?

Thanks.

Comment: If you could provide the code - that would be great :)

Comment: Was a solution found?

Answer (score 0):

I might have solved the exception problem related to multthreading.

## I added two statements to loading model so that it looks like this:

```
model = load_model(".....")
import tensorflow as tf 
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

#then in the def mlProcess(...), I added  two statements, so the code now looks as follows:-

```
global graph
with graph.as_default():
      while True:
```

Answer (score 0):

@Walid's answer is correct and for anyone interested in the "why" please refer to: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2397 and check out `Avital's` comment.

Cheers!